# How to find output response of filter circuit if transfer function is too complex?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, parametric-functions

I want to find unit step response of this transfer function. But I think, there is a problem, mathematica is not given any solution. Can anybody give me suggestion how to get the output response?

```
TransferFunctionModel[{{(r(1+s^4 c1 c2(l1+l2)+s^2(c1 l2+(c1+c2)lm)))/(r+s^5 c1 c2 l1 l2 lm+s^3(c1 l1 l2+c1 l1 lm+c2 l1 lm)+s^4(c2 l1 lm r c1+c2 l2 lm r c1)+s^2(l1 r c1+l2 r c1+lm r c1+lm r c2)+s l1)}},s]

Simplfy[OutputResponse[(TransferFunctionModel[{{(r(1+s^4 c1 c2(l1+l2)+s^2(c1 l2+(c1+c2)lm)))/(r+s^5 c1 c2 l1 l2 lm+s^3(c1 l1 l2+c1 l1 lm+c2 l1 lm)+s^4(c2 l1 lm r c1+c2 l2 lm r c1)+s^2(l1 r c1+l2 r c1+lm r c1+lm r c2)+s l1)}},s]),UnitStep[t],t]
```

[image]

And Result,

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load copy-paste-able Mathematica code (not an image) so that potential respondents can study this in their notebook sessions. Click on the `Edit` button under the post. Copy and paste directly from your input cell and use the `{ ... }` icon to format it as code. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to tell from an image, but is it possible that you did not put spaces between `R` and `C1` and between `R` and `C2` and between `s` and `L1` and thus it thinks `RC1`, `RC2` and `sL1` are three new unknown variables?

Comment: I can not copy code in there as well because of Subscript.

Comment: Variables are L1,L2,Lm,C1,C2,R.

Comment: Carefully check and correct this `TransferFunctionModel[{{(r(1+s^4 c1 c2(l1+l2)+s^2(c1 l2+(c1+c2)lm)))/(r+s^5 c1 c2 l1 l2 lm+s^3(c1 l1 l2+c1 l1 lm+c2 l1 lm)+s^4(c2 l1 lm r c1+c2 l2 lm r c1)+s^2(l1 r c1+l2 r c1+lm r c1+lm r c2)+s l1)}},s]`

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Hi, Bill. Is it correct in as shown above, in terms of format?